# Area of a 2D convex polytope made of halfspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, polygons, polytopes

For a computer program I am attempting to solve the area of a convex polytope defined by a finite number of halfspaces. I understand that this forms a polygon and given the vertices of a polygon I am able to solve for its area. However, this math is a bit out of my depth. Currently I am able to obtain the halfspaces which make up the polytope but do not know where to go from there in terms of finding their intersection and calculating the area of it.

Research:

[Find the vertices of the polytope](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295533/find-the-vertices-of-the-polytope)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#Intersection_of_half-spaces

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope
and http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_convex_polygon.htm

Comment: Thanks. The first link is beyond what I need to be able to do and well beyond my capabilities, I was hoping for a simpler solution for two dimensional convex polytopes. The second link is good except I do not know how to go from a set of half-spaces to the set of vertices used to find the area. Sorry if I'm asking for a lot, my only knowledge base is a linear algebra class I took 6 years ago :(

Comment: What is your internal representation of the half-spaces?